# rails_admin fails when class uses `belongs_to_active_hash`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have a class like this

```
class BTR::PaymentDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "btr_payment_details"
  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :user,         class_name: 'BTR::User'
  has_many :payment_events, class_name: 'BTR::PaymentEvent'
  has_many :charge_events,  class_name: 'BTR::ChargeEvent'

  belongs_to_active_hash :payment_method, class_name: 'PaymentMethod', foreign_key: :brand_code
end
```

When I try to access this model on Rails Admin panel, I get

```
[2017-02-13 13:37:02 +0100] [32a34e7c-26c2-43e9-89f8-7668225b2b85] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 612ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
[2017-02-13 13:37:02 +0100] [32a34e7c-26c2-43e9-89f8-7668225b2b85]
NoMethodError - undefined method `properties' for nil:NilClass:
  rails_admin (0.6.3) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/belongs_to_association.rb:19:in `block in <class:BelongsToAssociation>'
  rails_admin (0.6.3) lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:66:in `block in register_instance_option'
  rails_admin (0.6.3) lib/rails_admin/config/fields/base.rb:60:in `block in <class:Base>'
  rails_admin (0.6.3) lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:66:in `block in register_instance_option'
  rails_admin (0.6.3) lib/rails_admin/config/configurable.rb:40:in `block in register_instance_option'
```

so, for a quick fix, I removed the `:payment_method` from the listing

```
 config.model 'BTR::PaymentDetails' do
   exclude_fields :payment_method
 end
```

here is the `PaymentMethod` class

```
class PaymentMethod < ActiveYaml::Base
  set_root_path Rails.root.join('config')
  set_filename 'payment_methods'

  include ActiveHash::Associations
end
```

But I would like to understand what is causing this failure

I'm using rails_admin 0.6.3 with Rails 4.1.16

Comment: interesting , seems to work for me (however my belongs_to model was very different than yours). how about u strip down your belongs to model (payment details) to the bare minimum and see what's up . otherwise it might be a gem versions issue ?

Comment: I also bet it is some kind of version issue (since we are using a relatively old version of rails_admin). I want to know what do you man "strip down" the belongs_to model, since it has only 5 lines, I can't see anything to be removed here

Comment: you're right it's only the paper_trail and the custom name for the table, probably not the issue. so how possible is it to update your active admin and try again?

Comment: I'll propose it to the team (I haven't done it before because it is not planned for this sprint). Thanks, @Joel_Blum